# General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away while adding a thread

Tags: php, mysql

error while adding a thread to database showing this errors

```
Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=138803 in /home/u758467727/domains/joint2purchase.com/public_html/admin/add-thread.php on line 673

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in /home/u758467727/domains/joint2purchase.com/public_html/admin/add-thread.php:673 Stack trace: #0 /home/u758467727/domains/joint2purchase.com/public_html/admin/add-thread.php(673): PDO->exec('CREATE TABLE IF...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/u758467727/domains/joint2purchase.com/public_html/admin/add-thread.php on line 673
```

and code where this error is

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $lim (
   ID INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   USERNAME TEXT NULL,
   REPLY TEXT NULL,
   REPLYNAME TEXT NULL,
   MESSAGE TEXT NULL,
   DATE TEXT NULL,
   IMAGE TEXT NULL,
   TYPE TEXT NULL, 
   LIKES TEXT NULL,
   TROPHY INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
   MESSAGES INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
   JOINED TEXT NULL,
   FILES TEXT NULL,
   PHOTOS TEXT NULL,
   LIKERECEIVED INT(11) DEFAULT 0
   )";
$db->exec($sql);
```

Comment: Do you really need to use `TEXT` for all those columns? `TEXT` should normally be used for columns that can be very long, not short strings like dates and usernames.

Comment: ok instead of `TEXT` what can i use then

Comment: I can't see any reason why just creating a table should crash the server. Check the server log for reasons. If you need help in finding the log and interpreting the output, ask in [dba.se].

Comment: no checked error log showing the same error

Comment: You checked the error log for the MySQL daemon?

Comment: the error showing here `$db->exec($sql);`

Comment: So you haven't checked your MySQL daemon log. As I said above, if you don't know how to do that, ask for help in [dba.se]. This isn't a PHP programming question, there's a problem with you MySQL server.

Comment: yes i saw database error and showing the same thing

Comment: You understand that the error means that `mysqld` crashed, right? You need to find the system log that has the error messages from `mysqld`.